# How to share database file through flutter?

Tags: sqlite, file, flutter, encryption, share

I am currently working on a flutter app which stores data in sqlite. I need to share the table of sqlite through the share package.How can I do this? Do I have to create new file type? If yes then how to?

Thanks in advance.